# How to find product that is sold in all shops

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a table with shops(id, shop_name ,address), and another table sales(shops_id,product_id, product_name, price, quantity). How could i show a product that is sold in all shops.

my logic behind this is that i am couting the number of shops which are 10 and if a product is sold in all this 10 shops, but still doesnt work.

```
select product_id, product_name from sales
join shops on sales.shopsid = shops.id
group by(product_id, product_name)
having count(shop_name) = 10;
```

the result should be the product id and product name that is sold in all shops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- The question states: Find the products that were sold in EVERY shop
-- This is equivalent to: Find products for which "There does NOT EXIST a shop that did NOT sell the product"
-- This leads to the double "NOT EXISTS (NOT EXISTS())" solution to relational division.::

SELECT *
FROM product c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        -- find a shop that did not sell our product
        SELECT * FROM shop b 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                -- {product X shop} should not exist
                SELECT * FROM sales nx
                WHERE nx.product_id = c.product_id 
                AND nx.shop_id = b.shop_id
                )
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation, but I think you need `count(distinct)`:

```
select s.product_id, s.product_name
from sales s
group by s.product_id, s.product_name
having count(distinct s.shop_id) = (select count(*) from shops);
```

Comment: I don't get any result, and it must be product that is sold in all shops.

Comment: @SachiTakamori . . . The correct column should be `shop_id`, not `shop_name`.  If this returns no rows, then there are no such products.